# grails 2.4.4 jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, grails, datepicker

I can't manage to get the JQuery Datepicker working in my Grails 2.4.4 app.
With or without jquery-UI plugin it fails. Isn't it the case that the UI components integrated in the latest jquery plugin since it is usings jquery 1.11? How can a datepicker be added?

I have this code:

BuildConfig.groovy:

```
...
 plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.3"
        compile ":mail:1.0.7"

        build ':tomcat:7.0.54'

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        //compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
    (function($) {
        $('#spinner').ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    })(jQuery);
}
```

create.gsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
        <title>Create</title>               
    </head>
    <body>    
        <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
<%--        <jq:resource bundle="ui" components="datepicker" /> Gives a nullpointer exception!!!--%>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
          $("#install").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd'});
        })
        </script>

        <div class="body">
...
<input name="install" id="install" value="${fieldValue(bean:blaBlubInstance,field:'install')}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncomment the jquery-ui plugin under plugin section
and add the next line to your application.js

```
//= require js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min
```

and maybe you want to include in you appliaction.css the default theme

```
*= require themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: No sorry. I get this error in chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`
at this line:
`$("#install").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd'});`

Comment: @BioBer, Do you include your application.js and application.css in the main layout?